# Laravel 7.x select value is not passing in controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

```
<div class="form-group row">
     <label for="country_name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Country Name</label>

     <div class="col-md-6">
     <select id="country_name" type="text" class="form-control date @error('country_name') is-invalid @enderror" name="country_name" required autocomplete="country_name">
      <option vlaue="">Select</option>
     @foreach($countries as $countrys)
         <option vlaue = "{{ $countrys->id }}"> {{ $countrys->country }} </option>
    @endforeach
    </select>
     @error('country_name')
     <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
           <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
       </span>
      @enderror
      </div>
  </div>
```

dd dump 
I am getting this

```
 #attributes: array:5 [▼
    "company" => "test"
    "country" => "India"
    "address" => "test"
    "contact" => "1234567"
    "remarks" => "test"
  ]
```

Country should have id but I am getting the name instead of value.
Any one help me whit this one as I am new to Laravel

Comment: you should show us your controller that you getting dd() and form

Comment: I have sove it as i made a typo in form

Answer (score 0):

Your object should be similar to this before passing to the view.

```
        $countries = json_decode(json_encode( [
            ['id' => 1, 'country' => 'India'],
            ['id' => 2, 'country' => 'Bangladesh'],
            ['id' => 3, 'country' => 'Shrilanka'],
            ['id' => 4, 'country' => 'Afganistan'],
            ['id' => 5, 'country' => 'Nepal']
        ]));
/*
dd of the object would be look like this.
    array:5 [▼
  0 => {#248 ▼
    +"id": 1
    +"country": "India"
  }
  1 => {#222 ▼
    +"id": 2
    +"country": "Bangladesh"
  }
  2 => {#249 ▼
    +"id": 3
    +"country": "Shrilanka"
  }
  3 => {#251 ▼
    +"id": 4
    +"country": "Afganistan"
  }
  4 => {#252 ▼
    +"id": 5
    +"country": "Nepal"
  }
]
*/
```

[image: The HTML of your document should look like as in debug console.]

Comment: it was a typo in  select value so that why I was not getting the  value in dd dump

Comment: try to debug in this way, remove all HTML and paste 
     @foreach($countries as $countrys)
        <?php  print_r($countrys->id); ?>
    @endforeach

if you get a name that's mean $countrys->id is not an integer type